# Run a stored procedure to execute for all dates in future (30 years from now). But the stored procedure is only accepting a single date as input

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, while-loop

I have a stored procedure which is returning a result set in a single row for a single date entered. The stored procedure is returning details of the leap year and some month details. I want to run this stored procedure to return details of all the dates for the next 30 years and insert these values into a table.

This is how I am executing the stored procedure:

```
EXEC YDetail '20240116' -- given date
```

This returns the following result set:

| Date | LeapYear? | Month | MonthStart | TotalDaysInMonth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024-01-16 | Leap Year | 1 | 2024-01-01 | 31 |

I can also modify the stored procedure if that is easier option. Or, should I execute the stored procedure in a while loop? But how can we achieve that?

This is my stored procedure code:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[YDetail]    
    (@Date datetime)
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @inputYear INT, @monthname varchar(10)
    DECLARE @answer Varchar(30), @totaldaysMonth int, @monthstart datetime    

    SET @inputYear = YEAR(@Date)

    IF (@inputYear % 400 = 0 OR (@inputYear % 4 = 0 AND NOT @inputYear % 100 = 0))  
        SET @answer = 'Leap year';
    ELSE
        SET @answer = 'Not a leap year';
  
    SELECT @monthname = MONTH(@Date)

    SELECT @monthstart = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)

    SELECT @totaldaysMonth= DATEDIFF(dd, @monthstart, DATEADD(mm, 1, @monthstart))

    SELECT 
        @Date 'Date', @answer 'LeapYear?', @monthname 'Month', 
        @monthstart 'MonthStart', @totaldaysMonth as TotaldaysinMonth
END
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to create a calendar table. What you have is not efficient all. I strongly suggest that you take a look at [Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/)

Comment: "Or, should I execute the stored proc in a while loop?" - definitely not - SQL is intended to be set-based. Also if your input parameter is a date, then use the date datatype, not a datetime datatype. And you could add a parameter for the number of years, or an end date - whichever is more meaningful.

Comment: Note SSMS is a UI... and is not related to your query.

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking is known as a Calendar table and there are lots of ways creating it; here is one:

```
with Cal as (
select dateadd(day, TT*10000+T*1000+H*100+N*10+U, cast(getdate() as date) ) as Dte
from 
     ( values (0),(1)) TT(TT)
     cross join
     ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) T(T)
     cross join
     ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) H(H)
     cross join
     ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) N(N)
     cross join
     ( values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) U(U)

    )
select 
      Dte
    , case when datepart(dayOfYear,DATEFROMPARTS(year(dte),12,31))=366 then 'Leap Year' else '' end, Month(Dte) as Mth
    , dateadd(day, -day(Dte)+1, Dte) as MthStart
    , day(EOMONTH(Dte)) as DaysInMonth
 from Cal
 where Cal.Dte < dateadd(year, 30, getdate())
 order by 1
```

Comment: Are there no duplicates of this?

Comment: @DaleK, there might be duplicates, but I have searched some and they use scripts/CTE (not exactly the same); there might still be even closer ones, but I don't have time to inspect all. Feel free to remove this answer if you come across a duplicate.

Comment: Then maybe this will become the new dup closer :)